# ¿ C# como guardar una clase en una variable para ser llamada mas adelante?

Tags: c#

Tengo lo siguiente declarado:

```
miClase1 clase1 = new miClase1();
miClase2 clase2 = new miClase2();
```

llegado a un punto de codigo ahora quiero usar una de las dos clases dependiendo de una condicion y tengo lo siguiente:

```
object clase = null;
if ( opcion == 1 ) clase = clase1; else clase = clase2;

clase.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();
```

Pero no me deja hacer esto ultimo porque dice que el objeto clase no tiene declarado el metodo

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `interface`, `herencia` o `dynamic` recomiendo las 2 primeras opciones, la última deja espacio a errores

Answer (score 2):

Para poder hacer eso se necesita que *Clase1* y *Clase2* compartan una interfaz común o heredan de una clase padre

```
// Clase padre
public class ClasePadre
{
    public virtual void metodoComunEntreLasDosClases()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Método común en la clase padre");
    }
}

// Clase 1
public class Clase1 : ClasePadre
{
    public override void metodoComunEntreLasDosClases()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Método común en la clase 1");
    }
}

// Clase 2
public class Clase2 : ClasePadre
{
    public override void metodoComunEntreLasDosClases()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Método común en la clase 2");
    }
}
```

De esta forma se puede hacer tal cual lo que desea

```
    ClasePadre clase;

    if (opcion == 1)
    {
        clase = new Clase1();
    }
    else
    {
        clase = new Clase2();
    }

    clase.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();
```

Si no heredan de la misma clase padre, debe ejecutar cada clase dentro del condicional que le corresponde

```
    if (opcion == 1)
    {
        clase = new Clase1();
        clase.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();
    }
    else
    {
        clase = new Clase2();
        clase.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();
    }
```

Comment: Se puede hacer tambien asignando a un objeto. No me di cuenta y tenia que haber declarado la variable dynamic en vez de object

Answer (score 2):

Puedes es usar el delegado `Action` para dejar apuntando la función:

```
miClase1 clase1 = new miClase1();
miClase2 clase2 = new miClase2();
Action metodoComunEntreLasDosClases = opcion == 1 ? clase1.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases : clase2.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases;

metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenia que haber declarado el objeto como dynamic y no como object !! Pero en la version que uso de C# me sale error en compilacion con el mensaje:

Microsoft.Csharp.RuntimeBinder.CharpArgumentoInfo.Create !!

```
dynamic clase = null;
if ( opcion == 1 ) clase = clase1; else clase = clase2;
```

clase.metodoComunEntreLasDosClases();